# Mapview: Annotation image wrong after viewForAnnotation

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

The images on my Annotations are after adding for the first time good. Every annotation has a image with a number on it. When I scroll over the map and the method "viewForAnnotation" is been called (for second time) and the wrong images are been shown.. It seems that wrong annotation is been returned...

**ViewAnnotation Method:**

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
static NSString *identifier = @"pin";
VBAnnotationView *view = (VBAnnotationView *)[self.MapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (view == nil) {
    view = [[VBAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
return view; }
```

Note that the VBAnnotationView is my custom MKAnnotationView.

If the "view" is not nil the view found by "dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier" will be returned with the wrong image on it. When I comment out the check if "view == nill" the image on all the annotations are correct.

For optimalisation I check in the method "viewForAnnotation" if the annotation already exists. When removing the check if the annotation already exists, the images are shown correctly.

Comment: Do you mean MKAnnotationView instead of VBAnnotationView?

Comment: Hi Camus, VBAnnotationView is my custom MKAnnotationView. I have added this on the question.

Answer (score 0):

The dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier has no idea what the "right" image is for your annotation.. it's just giving you one to use.. you'll still need to configure it once you get it, by telling it what the annotation it's going to be for.

```
if (view == nil) {
    view = [[VBAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
else view.annotation=annotation;
```

Comment: the image is already been set, when the app runs the first time. The AnnotationView contains a image. What I currently did, is every annotation his own identifier.

Comment: That will work, but it defeats the purpose of using a reusable View to begin with.. if You're going to do it that way, you might as well just have an array or dictionary of views.